# How to test for presence of a string before another string on separate lines in a file

Tags: text-processing, sed, grep

I have a config file thus:

```
a: 123
b: abc
device: 1000
c: xyz

[old]
a: 120
b: xyz
device: 200
c: abc
```

The section "[old]" and everything below it is not always present.

How do I determine if the text "device: 1000" exists in the file BEFORE an optional "[old]" section?

I have been messing around with the following (broken) command syntax and I can't get it to do what I need...

```
sed -e '0,/^\[/;  /device: /p' configfile ; echo $?
```

...where `0,/^\[/` was supposed to limit the search between the start of the file and the first occurrence of "[" in the first column.  I am trying to get the return code to indicate whether the string was found or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `awk` is an option:

```
awk 'BEGIN{o=d=1} /\[old\]/{o=0} /device: 1000/&&o==1{d=0;exit} END{exit d}' file
```

Explanation:

- `BEGIN{o=d=1}`: initialize the variables
- `/\[old\]/{o=0}` if `[old]`: is found set `o=0`
- `/device: 1000/&&o==1{d=0;exit}`: if `device: 1000` is found and `[old]` is not found yet, set `d=0` and jump to the `END{}` block without examining the file further.
- `END{exit d}`: exit with the given value of `d`

Run it like this:

```
awk 'BEGIN{o=d=1} /\[old\]/{o=0} /device: 1000/&&o==1{d=0;exit} END{exit d}' file && echo "contains" || echo "contains not"
```

Comment: That'll do nicely.  It's about time I learned awk anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

I typically create a blob with sed by capturing multiple lines to a variable. This allows an inspection later if the required conditional is met.

`blob=“$(sed -n “/^abc.*$/,/^$/p” file)”`

Now we have the top portion of the file assigned to `”${blob}”`.

Now we just conditionally inspect `${blob}` of `[old]` exists:

`sh
if [ $(grep -c “^\[old/]$” file) -gt 0 ]; then
  echo “${blob}” | grep “^device” | grep -c 1000
fi`

I am sure this can be refactored but this will give you the results you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can look for `device: 1000` after having removed everything after `[old]`:

```
if sed '/^\[old\]/q' < file | grep -q 'device: 1000'; then
  echo OK
fi
```

With GNU `sed` (which you seem to be using given the GNU-specific `0,/.../` in your approach).

```
if sed -n '/device: 1000/q; /^\[old\]/Q1' < file; then
  echo OK
fi
```

(`q`, standard form of `Q0` exits with a 0 (success) exit status while `Q1` exits with exit status 1 (non-zero, so not success)).

With standard `sed`, you can't change `sed`'s exit status, but you could rely on whether it outputs something:

```
if [ -n "$(sed -n '/^\[old\]/q;/device: 1000/!d;=;q' < file)" ]; then
  echo OK
fi
```

(where `=` outputs the line number where the first occurrence of `device: 1000` is seen).

Or you could use `awk` which can set the exit status portably:

```
if awk '$0 == "[old]" {exit 1}; /device: 1000/ {exit 0}' < file; then
  echo OK
fi
```